# Cloning git repo results in error

Tags: git, egit

I have a git central repo on a shared folder in windows . We are a 2 member development team at present . Push and pull is configured on both the systems and is working fine .
   Now I want to set up a 3rd system for a new developer who is joining our team . I want to clone my central repo on to this new system . I am attempting to do this on eclipse mars and egit plugin . Whenever I try cloning my new system I get the following error .
                'Cloning from file://\ROBIN-PC\git\Project21.git' has encountered a problem.  want 40b1bc3160f72cd986eb32cc566a8e8e147bb315 not valid .
   I have also tried importing the project , committing it to a local repo and then trying to pull from the central repo . I can import and commit to the local repo . But when I try pulling branch master from the central repo I get almost the same kind of error that I have listed above . 
    It seems that git is missing a certain specific commit the hash key of which is listed . After searching through the repo history of my central repo . I found out that this commit is nothing but the commit id of the very first commit on the central repo . But I donot know if this is right or what to do about it .
    I have also seen that my local repo has push and pull URLs configured correctly but remote tracking is empty . I don't know if this is the problem .
   I am searched all the concerned links thrown up by google and the git tutorials and user manuals but cannot get this to work . I do not have much experience with git but was able to work just fine until now , when I encountered this problem . 
   Please help .

Comment: Have you tried to change your backslashes to forward slashes? You are using the file protocol anyways. Try "file:///ROBIN-PC/git/Project21.git"

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around solution:

1. Set up a GitLab Server on a Server
2. Create in this GitLab Server accounts for your developers and the project repo and invite them as members
3. Change the remote url of the repo in the working local repo on your machine and push then the local repo to the gitlab repo
4. Pull the gitlab repo to the new machine of your new developer

I hope you understand this solution :D My English is bad, I know ^^

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Having a git repo on a shared windows folder sounds dangerous, please don't do that :-) You don't even have to install a GitLab (even though it rocks, and there are several other alternatives as well), just setup a server and move the git repo there, and connect through ssh.

If you do not want to do this for whatever reason, please provide more details about your setup, and post the exact error messages.